# Building a Qt module from source and use it

Tags: qt

I've downloaded Qt from sources and thus I have the `qt-everywhere-opensource-src` folder containing all the Qt modules.

I needed to edit the bluetooth module, so I customized the QtConnectivity module (which contains Bluetooth and NFC APIs), and when building it, I'm getting **.so** and **.a** files.

Now my question is, how to use this new bluetooth library in a Qt project ?

**1. Replace Qt files in Qt installation folder** - Working

I've tried to put my generated libraries directly in my Qt sources, so I replaced original Qt files in **C:\Qt\5.9.6\android_armv7\lib** with my .so files for Android, and it is working great.

In my **.pro**, just with `QT += bluetooth`, everythings builds correctly, and in my application, I can access to my new functions.

**2. Import library as standalone library** - Not working

I've tried many ways to add bluetooth from my new sources, but none of them worked, here are some QMake variables I tried to set :

```
ANDROID_BUNDLED_JAR_DEPENDENCIES += \
    $$PWD/mylib/src/bluetooth/jar/QtAndroidBluetooth-bundled.jar
ANDROID_JAR_DEPENDENCIES += \
    $$PWD/mylib/src/bluetooth/jar/QtAndroidBluetooth.jar

ANDROID_LIB_DEPENDENCIES += \
    $$PWD/mylib/lib/android/libMyLib.so

ANDROID_PERMISSIONS += \
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH \
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN


LIBS += -L$$PWD/mylib/lib/ -lMyLib
```

Comment: instead of manually copying the libraries, you should run `make install`. If you compile the module with your already existing qmake, they will be installed into the Qt installation correctly, including modified headers etc.

Comment: Also, one thing that might work is to install the files to a different directory using `make INSTALL_ROOT=\some\directory install` and set the **environment** variable `QMAKEPATH=\some\directory` before running qmake in your project

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use this method and replace my Qt files in my Qt installation folder. I would like to import the bluetooth module as a standalone library, if this is possible

Comment: Then try my second comment - it will install the files in a folder of your choice instead.

Comment: I understand, but once the files are installed in a folder of my choice, how can I import these lib files in my project ?

Comment: Thats what the `QMAKEPATH` is for. It should tell qmake where to find the bluetooth module. So just add `QT += bluetooth` as you are used to and check if it works.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm new with Qt. I'll give it a try and keep you up then. But If I run `make INSTALL_ROOT=\some\directory install`, there will only be qtconnectivity build output in my `some/directory`, so what If i need my custom Qtbluetooth library + some other original Qt libraries ?

Comment: Well you can always remove the other ones manually afterwards

Comment: Can't I just import my files in my project ? `QMAKEPATH` doesn't seem to be a good solution for my case, since I need my project to be portable. If someone clones my project, I do not want to have to build the whole Qt source files just for one different module.